# Determine whether a PDF page contains text or is purely picture

Tags: java, parsing, itext, pdfbox

How to determine whether a PDF page contains text or is purely picture, using Java?

I searched through many forums and websites, but I can not find an answer yet .

Is it possible to extract text from PDF, to know if the page is in the format picture or text?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);  
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));              
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) { 
         // here I want to test the structure of the page !!!! if it's possible                         
         out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));  
        }
```

Comment: This seems pretty involved acctually. Maybe you'll need a bounty here

Comment: Thank you Mr Adel I hope so :)

Answer (score 8):

There is no water-proof way to do what you want.

Text can appear in different ways inside a PDF file. For instance: one can draw all the glyphs using graphics state operators instead of using text state. (I'm sorry if this sounds like Chinese to you, but I can assure you it's proper PDF language.)

If an ad hoc solution that covers the most common situations and misses an exotic PDF once in a while is OK for you, then you already have a good first workaround.

In your code, you loop over all the pages, and you ask iText if there's any text on the page. That's already a good indication.

Internally, your code is using the `RenderListener` interface. iText parses the content of a page and triggers methods in a specific `RenderListener` implementation. This is an implementation of a custom implementation: [MyTextRenderListener](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=282). This custom implementation is used in the [ParsingHelloWorld](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275) example.

There's also a `renderImage()` method (see for instance [MyImageListener](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=283)). If this method is triggered, you're 100% sure that there's also an Image in the page, and you can use the `ImageRenderInfo` object to obtain the position, width and the height of the image (that is: if you know how to interpret the `Matrix` returned by the `getImageCTM()` method).

Using all these elements, you can already get a long way to achieving what you need, but be aware that there will always be exotic PDFs that will escape all your checks.

Comment: Thank you very Much Mr@Bruno Lowagie

Answer (score 0):

With PDFBox 2.x you can try this:

```java
    private boolean hasText(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        return stripper.getText(doc).trim().length() != 0;
    }
```

Unfortunately it scans whole file first and does not stop at first text block. But you can receive whole text if you need.