# How to use Tesseract

Tags: pdf, tesseract

I'm trying to convert the images in a PDF file *(every page is a scanned image)* to text, using Tesseract (Tess4J) OCR, but it's not working: *(see comments in code)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PREFACE); // a PDF File D:\pdf\test.pdf
    int n = reader.getXrefSize();
    PdfObject object;
    PRStream stream;

    // Looking for image and manipulating image stream
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        object = reader.getPdfObject(i); // every time object null ?why
        if (object == null || !object.isStream())
            continue;

        stream = (PRStream)object;

        PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);
        BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(bi); //take Buffered iamge to transfor ti 
            System.out.println(result);  
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            stream.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question why `getPdfObject()` always returns `null` is irrelevant. There's a more important error in the code: you're assuming that every stream object in a PDF is an image stream. That's completely wrong. Even if all the content of your PDF consists of scanned images, you'll still have other streams, for instance page content streams that define the position of the scanned image on the page.

You should read my answer to [Determine whether a PDF page contains text or is purely picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570632/determine-whether-a-pdf-page-contains-text-or-is-purely-picture) and obtain the image bytes for all the image on each specific page from the [`ImageRenderInfo`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/ImageRenderInfo.html) class.

Please throw away your code and start anew. You've copy/pasted an example I wrote in the context of my book "iText in Action" but you didn't read the warning I added about this example. You'll have to step up and improve your questions.